# How to code deeply nested JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have five tables, let's call them A through E, each of which has a unique key and a foreign key which is the unique key of the `parent` table.

Thus: A->B->C->D->E

A has fields `A_key` and `B_key`; B has keys `B_key` and `C_key`, and so on ...

Given `A_key`, how do I `SELECT * from E`?  This has me stumped :-(

Do I need nested JOINs, or what?

And why won't the system let me submit the question without adding this at the end? Why does it say that it contains improper grammar?

---

[Update]

I have just realized that I phrased it wrongly.

It is `A->B->C->D<-E` - everything points "downwards", until the last, which points "upwards".

I don't see how I can change the database.  Is there any way to tweak @GiorgosBetsos answer?

As requested in comment, here are the tables. Given a campaign_id, I want to `SELECT * FROM taps`

```
mysql> describe campaigns;
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| campaign_id  | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title        | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description  | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| path_to_logo | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_time   | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| end_time     | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| paused       | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe destinations;
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| destination_id | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| campaign_id    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| url            | varchar(2048) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description    | varchar(2048) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe connections;
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| connection_id  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| destination_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description    | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tag_id         | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country        | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| county         | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| town           | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| post_code      | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| custom         | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe tags;
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tag_id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| tag_type      | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| customer_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| connection_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe taps;
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field       | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| tag_id      | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| time_stamp  | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| device_id   | text      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| device_type | text      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why don't you give your actual table and column names. It will make your life easier when interpreting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will let you select all the columns from the `taps` table:

```
SELECT
taps.tag_id,
taps.time_stamp,
taps.device_id,
taps.device_type
FROM campaigns AS camp
INNER JOIN destinations AS dest
ON dest.campaign_id = camp.campaign_id
INNER JOIN connections AS conn
ON conn.destination_id = dest.destination_id
INNER JOIN tags 
ON tags.connection_id = conn.connection_id
INNER JOIN taps
ON taps.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE camp.campaign_id = :campaign_id
```

You CAN replace the 4 rows after the `SELECT` with `taps.*`, but using `*` is bad practice, as if you ever add any columns in the future, you will start getting back different results.

Also, this query should be more efficient than the one provided by Giorgos, as `EXISTS` will, in general, not optimize as well as a `JOIN` will.

(I swear I'm not following you around and trying to one up your answers, Giorgos, I just happened to run across 2 of the same questions as you and thought I could provide a better solution.)

From how you describe the problem you are having, about this being a "deeply nested JOIN" suggests that you are viewing database relations incorrectly, as many, including myself, first do when still relatively inexperienced with databases.

## Introduction to thinking with sets

The database is going to take the list of `INNER JOIN`s above, and decide on one to start with. In this case, it will start with the `campaigns` table, because it knows it can get the smallest result back from that table (one row, or none, if none match the `campaign_id`.)

From there, it will build off of that one row, and for each record in the `destinations` table, it will find all those with a matching row `ON` the `campaign_id` column. From there, it will add the `destination_id` to its results, one for each row in the `destinations` table that was matched.

Then, for each row in its results (let's say there were 3 destinations match), it finds the matches all the connections with the same `destination_id` as it has in its result set. It then adds the `connection_id` to its results, one for each row in the connections table, for each given `destination_id`. Let's say the 3 destinations had 0, 1, and 4 connections, each. This means the database is now holding a result set up 5 rows (the `destination_id` without any `connections` was dropped from the result, because we are using `INNER JOIN`s.)

The process repeats down the line, until it finally reaches the `taps` table, and all the information from that table is added to the result. Finally, it grabs just the columns you want from the information it is holding on to, and returns the rows from the `taps` table.

Importantly though, **you don't have tell it the order to work in**. The following query is equivalent, from the database's point of view:

```
SELECT
taps.tag_id,
taps.time_stamp,
taps.device_id,
taps.device_type
FROM taps
INNER JOIN tags
ON taps.tag_id = tags.tag_id
INNER JOIN connections AS conn
ON tags.connection_id = conn.connection_id
INNER JOIN destinations AS dest
ON conn.destination_id = dest.destination_id
INNER JOIN campaigns AS camp
ON dest.campaign_id = camp.campaign_id
WHERE camp.campaign_id = :campaign_id
```

Note, that while the order is reversed from our perspective, the database will still operate in the same order as described above. That is because the database is looking to start with the smallest set of rows, and then add one table at a time to the result.

You do NOT have to worry about the order, or any nesting. Worry only about telling the database how to compare the tables, via the `ON` statements. You can even put the tables (in this example) in pretty much any order you want, so long as any `ON` statements only refer to already defined tables (from our reading perspective, top to bottom.)

The second query of mine may actually be easier to understand the sets concept. Start with the information you want (the `taps` table) as the `FROM` clause. Then start `JOIN`ing tables that get you closer to the information you have in the `WHERE` clause, until you have provided enough information for the database engine to piece things together and grab the information you need.

Hopefully that is helpful to get you starting thinking down the right path (as someone did for me, around 5 years ago). If you have any questions, feel free to ask, and I'll use those to improve my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM E
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM A
   JOIN B ON A.B_key = B.B_key
   JOIN C ON B.C_key = C.C_key
   JOIN D ON C.D_key = D.D_key
   WHERE D.E_key = E.E_key AND A.A_key = ? )
```

Comment: I am still struggling with converting it to my actual table & column names :-)  What does that `SELECT 1` do?

Comment: @Mawg `SELECT 1` does the same thing as `SELECT *` or `SELECT (anything else)` when it is inside of an `EXISTS`. In other words: nothing special. This is because `EXISTS` only checks to make sure a row exists, and the database engine ignores whatever you put in the `SELECT` statement, assuming it is valid syntax.