# Mysql: test fetch for no matches

Tags: mysql

I have a query which should return a number of rows of the format

```
+---------------------+-------+
| Date                | Count |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2016-04-15 01:00:00 |    10 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

If there are no matches, the query reruns a lot of

```
+---------------------+-------+
| Date                | Count |
+---------------------+-------+
| Null                |     0 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

I would like to test for both of these conditions and for the former return some JSON and for the latter return empty JSON (not a lot of JONS 'None', '0').

I tried to peek the first row

```
   $firstRow = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   if ($firstRow['Count'] == 0) 
       $returnData = '';
   else
       $returnData = $sqlQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

However, it seems that 'peeking' the first row means that I can't afterwards `fetchAll()`, as the JSON data in that case is also empty.

Do I misunderstand? How can I code this check?

---

[Updfate] The problem is that the query is returning one row for each date, with `NULL, 0`.

If the data are "real", I can just `FETCH_ALL()` and then `json_encode()`, but inj the case that it is all lats of `NULL, 0`I don't want to do that, I wan to `json_encode()` an empty string and return that instead.

Comment: Could you share your query?

Comment: Calling `fetch()` and then `fetchAll()` results in 2 database queries. Since you want the results fetched if they exist, why not just call `fetchAll()` once,  and then use PHP to check if the count of the returned array is 1 with the value for Count equal to 0, replacing the returned string with json_encode([]) or whatever you want to do in that case?

Comment: Because the query always returns multiple rows.  I need to check if they are all `Null, 0` or not, but it is enough to check if just one is. I guess it would be better to do that with PHP than SQL.

Comment: Right, I'm saying that if you called `fetchAll()` once, you can then use PHP to check if only one row was returned, and whether it equals `Null, 0` or not. If it does, return whatever you wanted for the case of no data, and if it doesn't, you already have the data you need to return extracted into a PHP object that you can process and return.

Comment: But my problem is that the query is returning one row for each date, with `NULL, 0`. If the data are "real", I can just `FETCH_ALL()` and then `json_encode()`, but inj the case that it is all lats of `NULL, 0`I don't want to do that, I wan to `json_encode()` an empty string and return that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your query would likely be reformulated to return no tuples instead of NULL,0 tuples. However, a quick and dirty fix would be to run your query enclosed in another one filtering the NULL dates:

```
SELECT * FROM (<your current query>) x WHERE `Date` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Well, the query is yin the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531264/how-to-code-deeply-nested-join and it looks like just tacking on `WHERE `Date` IS NOT NULL` as you say, will work (+1) (unless it can be optimized better?)